# Multiple 'flavors' with multi language support

Tags: android, multilingual, android-productflavors

1. I have an app with two flavors - let's call them main & F1
2. The app supports two languages: English (default) and Japanese.
3. I also have 4 strings.xml files (for each flavor/lang combination):

   - `src/main/res/values/strings.xml`
   - `src/main/res/values-jp/strings.xml`
   - `src/f1/res/values/strings.xml`
   - `src/f1/res/values-jp/strings.xml`
4. Inside of each strings.xml file there is a string named "x", having different value in each file, **except** the file  `src/f1/res/values-jp/strings.xml`, where a string named "x" is missing.

Use case:
The phone languages is Japanese, chosen flavor F1. The "x" value is taken from src/main/res/values-jp/strings.xml.

Question:
Is it possible to priorize
`src/f1/res/values/strings.xml`
over
`src/main/res/values-jp/strings.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to change merge rules for resource(there is a way for manifest, but I didn't see any for resource). As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources#resource_merging), merge rules are as following:

`build variant > build type > product flavor > main source set > library dependencies`

But based on this, I was expecting that resource merge prioritize `src/f1/res/values/strings.xml` over `src/main/res/values-jp/strings.xml` because you are building `f1` flavor. **Therefore, this maybe is a bug, but I have not tested this myself.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
productFlavors {

    myFrenchFlavor {
     buildConfigField "String", "LOCALE", "\"fr\""
    }
    myEnglishFlavor {
      buildConfigField "String", "LOCALE", "\"en\""
    }
}
```

Comment: This probably can make a workaround, but I think this is not his problem. because if there are a lot of strings like this, this approach will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but someone that finds it might benefit from the answer.

From the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources), the resource name qualifier are defined accordingly to:

> The language is defined by a two-letter ISO 639-1 language code,
> optionally followed by a two letter ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 region code
> (preceded by lowercase r).

so the filename should be `src/main/res/values-ja` instead of `src/main/res/values-jp`.